# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: django, security, password-protection

I tried this code with the library django-zxcvbn-password when i do it without using this library everything work but when i use this library it seems like when i write a weak password the password field doesn't receive it and that lead to a NoneType Object because password is empty, and i don't know why but when i try it with a good password everything works perfectly.

I use this library for security purpose.

```
class SignUpForm(forms.Form)

    """password_regex = RegexValidator(
        regex=r'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$',
        message="Password must be at least 8 characters in length and contain at least one uppercase letter, "
                "one lowercase letter, and one digit. "
    )"""
    
    name_regex = RegexValidator(
        regex=r'^[A-Z][a-z]{2,149}$',
        message="Names must begin with an uppercase letter followed by lowercase letters."
    )
    username_regex = RegexValidator(
        regex=r'^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{5,149}$',
        message="Username must begin with a letter followed by letters or digits and have a length of at least 6 "
                "characters and a maximum of 150 characters. "
    )
    username = forms.CharField(validators=[username_regex], min_length=5, max_length=150)
    email = forms.EmailField(validators=[EmailValidator],
                             error_messages={'invalid': 'Please enter a valid email address.'})
    first_name = forms.CharField(validators=[name_regex], min_length=2, max_length=150)
    last_name = forms.CharField(validators=[name_regex], min_length=2, max_length=150)
    password = PasswordField()
    confirm_password = PasswordConfirmationField(confirm_with='password')
    #password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, validators=[password_regex], min_length=8)
    #confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("password2")
        print(password)
        score = zxcvbn(password, confirm_password)['score']
        if score <= 2:
            self.add_error("password", "Passwords do not match.")
        elif score == 3:
            self.add_error("password", "Passwords do not match.")

        if password and confirm_password and password != confirm_password:
            self.add_error("confirm_password", "Passwords do not match.")
```

I don't know what's happening and why it doesn't get the good password

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% autoescape on %}
<html>
<head>
  <title>SIGN UP</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/signup.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>SIGN UP</h1>
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <h3> If you already have an account sign in</h3>
    <button type="button"><a href='signin'>Sign In</a></button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
{% endautoescape %}
```

And the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 80, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 131, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 140, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 57, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 140, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 181, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django_extensions\management\technical_response.py", line 40, in null_technical_500_response
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\git\agenda_project\agenda\views.py", line 41, in signup
    print(form)
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\utils.py", line 67, in render
    context = context or self.get_context()
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 326, in get_context
    top_errors = self.non_field_errors().copy()
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 362, in non_field_errors
    return self.errors.get(
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 200, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 438, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 459, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\git\agenda_project\agenda\forms.py", line 55, in clean
    score = zxcvbn(password, confirm_password)['score']
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\zxcvbn\__init__.py", line 27, in zxcvbn
    matches = matching.omnimatch(password, ranked_dictionaries)
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\zxcvbn\matching.py", line 90, in omnimatch
    matches.extend(matcher(password, _ranked_dictionaries=_ranked_dictionaries))
  File "C:\Users\User.DESKTOP-TJSM0H2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\zxcvbn\matching.py", line 98, in dictionary_match
    length = len(password)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: The field is named "confirm_password" but you get the wrong key ("password2"?) from cleaned_data - `confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("password2")`

Comment: i guess your matching.py code is missing in qsn